# Append a row which contains spring tags by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I want to add a row to my table and this is a part of my code:

```
function AddOneRow(){
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
    newCell.innerHTML = '<form:input type="text" path="nom_etabl" class="round default-width-input" />';
}
```

I added this function to a button and when I want to open the page the server give me this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'nom_etabl' available as request attribut

because the row contain the **path** parameter which refer to a form in the body of the page so when the server read in the script "path" out of any form it return this error. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind The path attribute of the form ('e.g. nom_etabl) to a POJO attribute.
I guess you didn't do that...

Please look at this great example how to work with Spring MVC Form Tag Lib

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-textbox-example/

Comment: The problem is that the path must be into a form tag with commandName and I did that in the body of the page out of the table (because <form> is not valid inside of the table) .